# PHP Curl : Get data from XML after submission

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress, curl

I need to get the response after the form is submitted. The form is submitted to a remote API server.

Here is some of the code:

```
/*
     * Submits the data via a CURL session
     */
    private function sendDetails(){
        if(true || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '85.17.27.88'){
            $ch = curl_init($this->parseLink);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $this->parseRequestString($this->result)
            ));

            $this->returned = curl_exec($ch);
            $this->headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

            $this->result = $this->checkResponse();

            if(!$this->result)
                $this->setError($this->returned);
            elseif(isset($this->p['mobi-submit'])) {
                //redirect mobi users
                $_SESSION['enquire-success-name'] = $this->p['enquire-name'];
                wp_redirect('');
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo nl2br(var_export($this->result, true));
            exit;
        }

    }

    /*
     * Checks the response from the webservice for errors / success
     */
    private function checkResponse(){

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        try {
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->returned);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            return false;
        }       

        if($xml) {
            // If the response has a leadid attrib, then we submitted it successfully.
            if(!empty($xml[0]['leadid'])) {
                if(is_string($xml[0]))
                    $this->returned = $xml[0];
                return true;
            } 
            // If the errorcode is 7, then we have a resubmit and so it was successful.
            elseif(!empty($xml->errors->error[0]['code']) &&  $xml->errors->error[0]['code'] == "7") {
                if(is_string($xml->errors->error[0]))
                    $this->returned = $xml->errors->error[0];
                return true;
            }
            // Otherwise try set the response to be the errormessage
            elseif(!empty($xml->errors->error[0])){
                if(is_string($xml->errors->error[0]))
                    $this->returned = $xml->errors->error[0];
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise set it to the first xml element and return false.
            else {
                if(is_string($xml[0]))
                    $this->returned = $xml[0];
                return false;
            }
        } 
        // If the xml failed, revert to a more rudimentary test
        elseif(stripos($this->returned, $this->expected) !== false) {
            return true;
        } 
        // If that also fails, expect error.
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I did not write this code and I'm not so familiar with curl. I need to get the `$xml[0]['leadid']` response into another php file. Is this possible? Do I include the php file that has these function then create a new function? Or do I store it on my database then retrieve it from the database?

Would appreciate any help or further information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured this out on my own after playing around with the classes etc. :

```
//Get the type of lead that is submitted
$lead_type = $insureFormResult->p['enquire-type'];

//Get the leadid from xml
$xml = $insureFormResult->returned;
if($xml){
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$leadid = $xml1->xpath("/response/@leadid")[0];
}
```

Thanks for your answers and inputs though!

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from $this->returned['leadid'] if returned class member is public OR create a function

```
public function getReturnedVal($key = 'leadid'){
  if(isset($this->returned[$key])){
    return $this->returned[$key];
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how would I echo this on another php file?

Comment: the simple way is to save in a $_SESSION if this is a same host or store in a DB

Comment: the simple way is to save in a $_SESSION if this is a same host or store in a DB, if different host and application header("Location: host/fileName.php?id=".$idvalue);

Comment: How would I store it in a session?

Comment: session_start(); $_SESSION['leadid'] = $this->returned['leadid'];

Answer (score 2):

Just as you said in your question, your easiest option rather than dealing with sessions or databases to store the API response would be to include your script on the PHP file where you need the data (`include('curl_api_script_file.php');`) and then use a function like @volkinc suggested to echo the data into your PHP response page where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `file_put_contents('http://path.to.another.php',$this->returned['leadid']);` if you have fopen wrappers enabled.
The other php would have to just capture the transferred data.